# What does scale exactly mean?

Tags: terminology, scales, scale-construction

I am not so familiar with statistical concepts. I am preparing a questionnaire to measure underlying constructs that affect pedestrian's road crossing behavior. However, I came across this term called "scale". Earlier I used to think that scale simply means measurement scale (e.g. nominal, ordinal, numerical etc.). But I have seen people using the term "scale construction".
Could someone me tell me what it means by constructing a scale (as asked in this question: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_fundamental_procedure_for_Scale_construction)?

Update: I have updated the question to be more clear and precise.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide a link to where you read the word that confused you. With PCA it could just mean multiplication.

Comment: I mentioned PCA just to tell that how I had to use statistics.
My question about "scale" was not related to PCA. I am sorry for the confusion.
However, following link contains what I wanted to ask about:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_fundamental_procedure_for_Scale_construction

Comment: That link is talking about [rating scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rating_scale). An appropriate English definition of this use of the word scale is *a set of numbers, amounts, etc., used to measure or compare the level of something*

Comment: "scale" is one of those words that have multiple meanings, each in their own context. At least three come immediately to mind in statistics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This word has many meanings, e.g.

- [*measurement scale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) (nominal, ordinal, etc.) is a classification of variables in statistics in terms of mathematical operations that can be applied to them,
- in probability and statistics *scaling factor* of probability distribution, so $Y = bX$ is a random variable defined in terms of random variable $X$ scaled by the $b$,
- what follows, we have [*location-scale distributions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family) with location $a$ and *scale $b$ parameters*, $Y = a + bX$ (e.g. mean and variance in normal distribution) that lead to transforming probability density function to $f_Y = f_X(\tfrac{X-a}{b})\,/\,b$, and cumulative distribution function to $F_Y = F_X(\tfrac{X-a}{b})$,
- in psychometrics people often call the questionnaire as *"scale"*, e.g. [Wechsler Adult Intelligence Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechsler_Adult_Intelligence_Scale) is one of the most popular IQ tests.

What exactly it means depends on context.

Comment: Helpful, but I think your second bullet point conflates two distinct ideas. A scale parameter measuring spread (dispersion is another common word) generally has units and dimensions that are the same as the original variable, or is reducible to such. So a normal distribution fittted to data on weights has a standard deviation with the same units and dimensions; and similarly in general.  Your example $Y=bX$ has $b$ as what might often be called a multiplicative or scale factor (rather than a scale parameter).

Answer (score 1):

A guess:

"scale" in PCA could arise form question "should we standardize variables before running PCA?".

The answer is "Yes", because if we do not, a **scale** of variable affects results. If, for example, one of variables is in centimeters and we change it's **scale** to meters, we would get completely different results in PCA.

Also if **scale** of one of the variables is from 0 to 1 and another from 0 do 1000, the later would have greater impact on PCA results.

So, my guess is that **scale** here means "unit", "range", "extent" etc.

Plus, `R` function that performs standardization is... `scale` :)